# Availability test still running after application insight was deleted

Tags: azure

We had an Application Insight instance defined with 2 availability tests inside. I was not able to edit or delete the availability tests, so I just deleted the Application Insight instance. However, the availability tests are still running somehow. How can I get rid of them ?

I tried searching inside Azure for the Application Insight and Availability Tests, but they are gone.